# Efficient way to sum over an index repeated more than twice

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking for an efficient way of computing sums of the type
$$D_{jk} = \sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ik} C_{i}$$
for large numerical matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Here is a slow solution:

```
DD = Table[Sum[AA[[i, j]] BB[[i, k]] CC[[i]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, m}, {k, 1, m}]
```

What's a fast way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
n = 4;
m = 3;
aa = Array[a, {n, m}];
bb = Array[b, {n, m}];
cc = Array[c, n];
dd = Table[Sum[aa[[i, j]] bb[[i, k]] cc[[i]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, m}, {k, 1, m}];
```

You can [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) `aa` and [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) it with `bb cc`:

```
Transpose[aa].(bb cc) == dd
```

> True

Alternatively, you can `Transpose` `aa cc` and `Dot` it with `bb`:

```
Transpose[aa cc].bb ==dd
```

> True

Comparison with `Table/Sum` combination:

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 100;
m = 50;
aa = RandomReal[1, {n, m}];
bb = RandomReal[1, {n, m}];
cc = RandomReal[1, n];
dd = Table[Sum[aa[[i, j]] bb[[i, k]] cc[[i]], {i, 1, n}], {j, 1, m}, {k, 1,   m}]; //
   RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.417

```
ee1 = Transpose[aa].( bb cc) ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000051

```
ee2 = Transpose[aa cc].bb ; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.000045

```
dd == ee1 == ee2
```

> True